# Using Spring-Actuator in combination with ObjectDB

Tags: spring-boot, objectdb, spring-actuator

I am implementing a program in Spring-Boot using ObjectDB. To actually use ObjectDB I have followed this approach https://www.objectdb.com/forum/2523 which is working perfectly.

However, as soon as I want to use Spring-Actuator then I am getting the following errors:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.orm.jpa.HibernateMetricsAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is com.objectdb.o.UserException: Unsupported unwrap(org.hibernate.SessionFactory.class) for EntityManagerFactory
```

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

I am using the exact same code as in the link. I have added Spring-Actuator in the pom like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The failure is occurring because Spring Boot is trying to unwrap the JPA `EntityManagerFactory` to get Hibernate's `SessionFactory`. It's attempting to do this as you have Hibernate on the classpath (it's a dependency of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`). According to the JPA specification, `unwrap` should throw a `PersistenceException` "if the provider does not support the call". Spring Boot catches `PersistenceException` in case `unwrap` isn't supported. Unfortunately, ObjectDB is throwing `com.objectdb.o.UserException` which isn't spec compliant. I'd recommend raising this as an ObjectDB bug.

You can avoid the problem by excluding Hibernate from the classpath. This will stop Spring Boot from attempting to unwrap Hibernate's `SessionFactory`, preventing the ObjectDB bug from occurring. You can do so by adding an exclusion to the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the report and the diagnosis. ObjectDB 2.8.4 was fixed to throw an instance of PersistenceException on unsupported unwrap calls (actually an instance of a subclass, but hopefully it would be caught now as expected).

Comment: Yes, thanks!
I can confirm that both solutions (adding the exclusion and/or upgrading ObjectDB) work.